# How can I create a test script in QTP which performs right click operation under any windows folder?

Tags: vbscript, automation, qtp, hp-uft

I want to create a test script in QTP which when I execute does 'Right mouse button' operation on any windows folder and select any specified Popupmenu eg. Refresh.

I have added the folder under QTP OR and its reflects the black folder area as 'WinList'.

This is the added OR hierarchy that I added:
Window("abc").WinObject("Items View").WinList("Items View")

So Basically i want to perform RMB Operation over this WinList and select any option under the PopupMenu.

Comment: Why don't you use the play and record feature to better understand what you need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Description Object** for collecting data of all object which you are interested in. [Here](http://relevantcodes.com/qtp-all-about-the-description-object-description-create/) 
is nice how-to. Then spy object (to click on - in your case WinList object) and manage its properties by **WinListEntry.SetToProperty("propertyName","valueToSet")** to locate and click custom menu entry.

Answer (score 0):

```
Window("abc").WinObject("Items View").WinList("Items View").Click micNoCoordinate, micNoCoordinate, micRightBtn
```

should do the job.

Source: Online help of WinList.

I hope you get the pun intended ;-)